# Python: grequest and request give different response

Tags: python, grequests

**My original task:** Using [Trello API](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/list), get data through HTTP GET requests. Run requests and process responses asynchronously, if possible. The API provider uses "https://" URL I access to with some key and token.

**Tools I used:**

- Python 2.7.10 | Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit) | (default, May 28 2015, 16:44:52) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
- `requests` library (just
  imported without installation)
- `grequests` library (installed via pip
  from [this git repo](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests.git))

**Original task result:** Only `requests` library worked, I've got Trello API's response, great. `grequests` library was failing with status_code = 302.

I tried to understand why it happens and wrote two reproducible scripts.

**Script A** : `requests` library used:

```
import requests

urls = [
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.facebook.com/",
    "http://www.facebook.com/",
    "http://www.google.com",
    "http://fakedomain/",
    "http://python-tablib.org"
]

# Run requests:
for url in urls:
    print requests.get(url).status_code
```

**Console output A** (having some exception because of `http://fakedomain/`) :

```
200
200
200
200
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "req.py", line 14, in <module>
    print requests.get(url).status_code
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(11001, 'getaddrinfo failed'))
```

**Script B** : `grequests` library used with `map` to send asynchronous requests:

```
import grequests

# This function will execute set of instructions when responses come:
def proc_response(response, **kwargs):
    # do something ..
    print response

# Request exception handler:
def my_except_handler(request, excetion):
    print "Request failed : " + request.url

urls = [
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.facebook.com/",
    "http://www.facebook.com/",
    "http://www.google.com",
    "http://fakedomain/",
    "http://python-tablib.org"
]
# Here is the list of tasks we build and run in parallel later:
actions_list = []

# Tasks list building:
for url in urls:
    action_item = grequests.get(url, hooks = {'response' : proc_response})
    actions_list.append(action_item)

# Run grequests:
print grequests.map(actions_list, exception_handler=my_except_handler)
```

**Console output B** :

```
<Response [302]>
<Response [302]>
<Response [200]>
<Response [301]>
<Response [302]>
<Response [200]>
Request failed : https://www.google.com
Request failed : https://www.facebook.com/
Request failed : http://www.facebook.com/
Request failed : http://fakedomain/
[None, None, None, <Response [200]>, None, <Response [200]>]
```

All I can conclude based on this information and my relatively small experience is the following - because of some reason `grequests` is rejected by remote websites `requests` works normally with. As long as 302 means redirection of some kind, it seems that `grequests` can not get data from source it is redirected to when `requests` can. `allow_redirects=True` in `get` method in Script B didn't solve the issue.

I wonder why libraries give different response. It is possible that I miss something, and these two scripts have to return different results by design, not because of differences between two libraries.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## grequests works well for me

Here is my script `b.py`, which I run via `$ py.test -sv b.py`:

```
import pytest
import grequests


@pytest.fixture
def urls():
    return [
        "https://www.google.com",
        "https://www.facebook.com/",
        "http://www.facebook.com/",
        "http://www.google.com",
        "http://fakedomain/",
        "http://python-tablib.org"
    ]


# This function will execute set of instructions when responses come:
def proc_response(response, **kwargs):
    # do something ..
    print "========Processing response=============", response.request.url
    print response
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print response.request.url
        print response.content


# Request exception handler:
def my_except_handler(request, exception):
    print "Request failed : " + request.url
    print request.response


def test_it(urls):
    # Here is the list of tasks we build and run in parallel later:
    actions_list = []

    # Tasks list building:
    for url in urls:
        action_item = grequests.get(url, hooks={'response': proc_response})
        actions_list.append(action_item)

    # Run grequests:
    print grequests.map(actions_list, exception_handler=my_except_handler)
```

It is based on your code, it is only rewritten to easy my experimentation.

### Results: Final results are 200 or None

Last printout of my test shows:

```
[<Response [200]>, <Response [200]>, <Response [200]>, <Response [200]>, None, <Response [200]>]
```

This is what is expected.

Note, that you could have some temporary problems with fetching the data, there are too many players
participating.

### Conclusion: different response processing confused you

The difference is, that with `requests` you are asking for final result while with `grequests` you
deploy `process_response` hook, which is called for each response including redirect ones.

**The `requests` processing goes through redirect too, but this temporary response is not reported.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Jan. I appreciate your effort to show and explain the thing. This is my first question at SO, I was very impressed how fast some help came in.